# ADB2C password reset policy

Tags: angular7, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, reset-password

Is there any way for directly login/signin after confirming the new password in reset password policy. Currently I am using ADB2C reset password policy for resetting password in my angular website using MSAL Library. But now after resetting password, user want to enter login credentials again. 
sample code is shown below

```
 public forgotPassword(): void {
    this.clientApplication.authority = environment.authority + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.resetPasswordPolicy;
   // this.resetPassword();
   this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
  }



  this.clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority,
      this.authCallback,
      { validateAuthority: false,//required for enabling JS
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl:false
      }
    );

  authCallback = (erroDesc, token, error, tokenType) => {
    var _this = this;
    const client = window.msal as Msal.UserAgentApplication;

    if (tokenType == "id_token") {
    client.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes);
     .then(
       function (accessToken: any) {
         _this.saveAccessTokenToCache(accessToken);


         });
       }, function (error: any) {
         console.info("error:", error);
       })
  }
```

while calling acquiretokenpopup, adb2c login page will open again and I need accesstoken for accesing backend API.

Is reset password policy passing accessToken without calling acquireTokepopup or acquireTokenRedirect? or any other solution for this scenario? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried calling acquireTokenSilent with the sign in policy id after password reset completes?

Comment: Hi @ann are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity, the issue i mentioned in the question is solved but i have another query -->how to use aquiretokenRedirect instead of aquiretokenpopup?. If I used aquiretokenRedirect where i will add the functions after getting token?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Can you please raise a New SO question and Please share the scenario and issue you are facing